# Unresolved Identifier Error 'imageArray'

Tags: swift, xcode

why is my variable not being recognized. It is on a second view controller.

```
import UIKit 

class PacksPage: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var iCarouselView: iCarousel! 

    var imageArray = [ UIImage(named:"PeoplePack"),
                       UIImage(named:"MachineryPack"), 
                       UIImage(named:"ArchitecturePack") ,
                       UIImage(named:"MoneyPack"),
                       UIImage(named:"AnimalPack"), 
                       UIImage(named:"PrimitivePack") , 
                       UIImage(named:"GalacticPack") ]

    //...
} 

extension ViewController: iCarouselDelegate, iCarouselDataSource { 
    func numberOfitems(in carousel: iCarousel) —> Int { 
        return imageArray.count 
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you should pass that variable to this viewController and use the variable defined in this viewController.

Comment: I made a .swift file and linked the view controllers data source to it.

Comment: Did you want an extension of `PacksPage` instead?

Comment: Do not edit your question with a new, separate issue.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this community, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
extension PacksPage: iCarouselDelegate, iCarouselDataSource
```

In place of

```
extension ViewController: iCarouselDelegate, iCarouselDataSource
```

Try it and share your results.

Comment: I continued coding and the same error popped up for nill, I updated the code above can you check it out?

Comment: I am not seeing any edits. Can you explain more about the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you get this error is that this variable does not exist on the ViewController. You can create an extension of the PacksPage viewController.